# C# (async / await) loop in task block my main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

```
private async Task<PortalODataContext> CallConnection(Connection connection)
    {
        bool cancel = false;
        connection.Connected = true;
        var task = getConnection(connection);

        while (!cancel && !task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            if (connection.Disconected)
            {
                cancel = true;
            }
        }

        return await task;
    }
```

That is my function that I call on the main thread Like so :

```
PortalODataContext portalContext = await this.CallConnection(connectionOpen);
```

I am new to async and await so I'm just trying to figure out why My task"CallConnection" block my main UI thread ... can you guys help me ?

Ohh and there is the GetConnection :

```
private Task<PortalODataContext> getConnection(Connection connection)
    {            
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var context = connection.ConnectToPortal();
                connection.ListTemplateLib = this.ShellModel.ConnectionManager.GetTemplateLibrarys(connection);
                connection.ListTemplateGrp = this.ShellModel.ConnectionManager.GetTemplateGroups(connection, connection.TemplateLibraryId);
                connection.ListTemplates = this.ShellModel.ConnectionManager.GetTemplates(connection, connection.TemplateGroupId);
                return context;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
       });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you would like to know why your main thread is being blocked?

Comment: Yes I can't figure it out

Comment: It looks like your actual IO isn't inherently asyncrhonous, so you're just creating sync over async methods.  You really shouldn't be doing this.  If the work is inherently synchronous, you should just be doing it synchronously.  If some higher level method needs to, say, offload the work to another thread to keep a UI thread responsive, they can do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Becasue the `Thread.Sleep`

async/await split your method in two, before and after the `await`. In the first half you have a `Thread.Sleep`, causing the caller thread to freeze.

Use:

```
private async Task<PortalODataContext> CallConnection(Connection connection)
{
    bool cancel = false;
    connection.Connected = true;
    var task = getConnection(connection);

    while (!cancel && !task.IsCompleted)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        if (connection.Disconected)
        {
            cancel = true;
        }
    }

    return await task;
}
```

I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: That is right. Honestly all method feels strange to me :) Maybe because it is just an excerpt.

Comment: I'm trying to cancel the task when I click on my Disconnect Button

Comment: @Cedric Look into [task cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has to be cooperative, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you call an async task , you have to wait for a result.

The benefit of asyncs is that you can run two processes in a method, but just inside that method. 
Before you leave that block both processes must be unified again. That makes you easier to run different processes not having to write delegates and Locks for objects involved.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx) to see what happens in an async methods. There is a diagram there that can help you to clarify the flow.

In your code you don't need the Threed.Sleep. The CallConnection method won't return anything until getConnection returns something. Then you can continue in your main Thread.

Hope that help you.